# Making tint colour's size the same with button's size?

Tags: ios, uibutton

I have three buttons that are the same size; as you can see in the picture below, they are aligned and I created a TabView with then and whenever I tap any of those three, only a portion of the button's colour changes:

[image]

How can I change the tint colour's size the same size with the button's size?

Comment: if you want edits in code, then show it what you have done.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the entire button color then you need to set the backgroundColor.

```
myButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
```

The tint color only sets the text color and border color of a button.